# level 12: how to get rid of bugs s and i?

Tags: vim-adventures

I managed to "tame" them by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd>, but I can't get rid of them. Thus, they are blocking deletion and further progress...

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Can you give specific details on the puzzle?  Some of use know vim but not the game so we may be able to help by knowing the letters/words/etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain, but I think @Sven is asking about the "LeChuck" puzzle:
[image: "LeChuck" puzzle in the Underground buffer, Vim Adventures level 12]

So, maybe it is related to this question: [Stuck with the “S”-Bug in the LeChuck Text in level 12](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126748/stuck-with-the-s-bug-in-the-lechuck-text-in-level-12)

Anyway, this is what worked for me:

1. Destroy the **s** bug with a **sentence** editing command

   > like `d` `a` `s`
2. Destroy the **i** bug with an **inner** editing command

   > like `d` `i` `p`

> 3. Finally, delete the red-marked text with "delete a paragraph", `d` `a` `p`