# Stuck with the "S"-Bug in the LeChuck Text in level 12

Tags: vim-adventures

I am stuck with the "S"-Bug in the LeChuck Text.

Obviously I should delete the whole text above the capital letter "T" for example by pressing "dgg", leaving just:

```
Then things really got ugly.
```

But the stupid bug is in the way and since you can not edit that text, killing it with a simple "5s" combo won't work...

You reach this text block nearing the end of the level after opening the left of the two red doors. I already cleared the right side and unlocked the "."-Command.

Comment: Oh i just found out how to kill the bug. I used the delete a sentence command "das". But i still can't delete the right amount of text since "dgg" won't work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah so this is how u do it:

1. Kill the bug by using a sentence delete command like "dis".
2. Delete the whole paragraph by pressing "dap".

Hope this is helpful to someone else.